# Does the .NET binary serializer encode assemby information?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've been developing a game and part of the process was going to be a custom level tool and file format. I had created a small console application that generated a 'LevelAsset' object which contained only primative data types. The problem arises when I try to deserialize that data within my unity game. I didn't copy any code from my console app and rewrote both the 'LevelAsset' object and Deserialization code from scratch. Yet when I run the game, I get an error saying I'm missing the "Level Tool, version=1.0.0.0" assembly, which is from my original console app. How is this occuring. Is the binary serializer encoding information about the project?

**Edit:** So upon further investigation it appears that the BinnaryFormatter does indeed include information about the project in the form of a file header. So my new question is now: How on earth do I serialize without headers?

Comment: [Serialization guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/serialization-guidelines#choosing-the-right-serialization-technology-to-support): "AVOID supporting runtime serialization or XML serialization just for general persistence reasons. Prefer data contract serialization instead"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit of digging its fairly obvious whats happening. BinaryFormatter does indeed encode project information in its file headers. If you want to avoid this you should use binary writer instead.